# Making a bangle from $6$ green and $6$ blue beads

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

How many different ways are there to make a bangle by selecting $6$ beads from $6$ green beads and $6$ blue beads?

(The bangle is a closed loop, and rotations of the same bangle are to be counted only once. The upside-down version of a bangle is not considered to be the same bangle.)

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder about *ggbbgb* and *bbggbg*. Are they really different? If you took the first bangle off and put it back on backwards (*I.e.* flipping it upside down) - wouldn't it be identical to the second as it's now reversed?

Comment: imagine the beads have a top and a base (V) - they ARE NOT the same bangle; @PaulEvans

Comment: But surely the beads can be spun around if that's the case; @JonMarkPerry

Comment: @PaulEvans;  might as well have 2 bangles...

Comment: @PaulEvans; mind you, if the beads are orientable its a different Q

Comment: @JonMarkPerry that's what I was just thinking because the beads could also be asymmetric left-to-right. But surely where're creating a new question now. Most beads are symmetrical anyway and "blue" and "green" as the only description kind of implies that.

Comment: how about 'oriented circular arrangements'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are:

> 13 different bangles.

Because:

> Imagine a 6 digit binary number where the 1s are green and the 0s are blue.
>  This number can rotated to give the same bangle.
>  Doubling for swaping blue with green when there's an unequal number gives:
>  2 for 111111 -  2 numbers.
>  1 for 101010 -  2 numbers.
>  2 for 110110 -  6 numbers.
>  1 for 111000 -  6 numbers.
>  2 for 111100 - 12 numbers.
>  2 for 111110 - 12 numbers.
>  1 for 110010 - 12 numbers.
>  2 for 111010 - 12 numbers.
>  ---------------------------------------------
>  13 bangles for all 64 numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> 14

Argument:

- If we cut the bangle up, we get a green-blue string with six symbols; altogether, there are $2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2=64$ such strings.
  However, now we are over-counting, as many rotations yield rotated versions of the same bangle.
- First, there are the two strings $bbbbbb$ and $gggggg$ of period length 1; they both are counted only once. (This case yields two strings and two bangles.)
- There is one string $bgbgbg$ of period length 2; this string yields the same bangle as $gbgbgb$. (This case yields two strings and one bangle.)
- There are two strings of period 3: $bbgbbg$ and $ggbggb$.
  These strings yield the same bangles as $gbbgbb$ and $bgbbgb$, respectively
  as $bggbgg$ and $gbggbg$. (This case yields six strings and two bangles.)
- The remaining $54$ strings correspond to nine bangles, that each is counted in six rotated versions. (This case yields 54 strings and nine bangles.)

Altogether, this yields $2+1+2+9=14$ bangles.

Comment: Actually it seems that the answer is $13$, not $14$. Refer the Paul's answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can consider $4$ cases:

All green:
$gggggg$

One blue:
$gggggb$

Two blues:
$ggggbb$
$gggbgb$
$ggbggb$

Three blues:
$gggbbb$
$ggbgbb$
$gbgbgb$
$gbggbb$

By symmetry on green/blue, this gives a total of $14$ bangles.

Note that $ggbgbb$ and $gbggbb$ are different because of their orientations.

Comment: I now think *ggbgbb* and *gbggbb* are the same as turning one upside down gives the other.